# Fix corrupted ntfs drive to save files

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, mount, ntfs

i have a ntfs drive that i often use on a mac, so i was trying to make it writable and followed several online tips.

inside etc/fstab/ there was a line LABEL=Untitled none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse but still not working, so tried to use the following commands

```
sudo umount /Volumes/Untitled
sudo mkdir /Volumes/Mount
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/Mount
open /Volumes/Mount
```

the folder appeared and allowed me to write files but after few minutes it disappeared and my drive seemed to be damaged.

- tried to open on **mac** and it showed the drive but if i tried opening it, it seemed empty even if in the drive information shows the right space: 955occupied and 45free
- tried to open on **linux** and it showed *Unable to access 1tb volume. Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /media/ubuntu. Unknown error when mounting*
- tried to open on windows and it showed the icon but if I tried to enter it got stuck.  Then I tried to right click and start defrag or disk cleanup it said can’t access the disk

it seems like I have corrupted the filesystem, but files are there.

how can i save my data? is there a way to fix the filesystem? i wouldn't want to use a data recovery software cause it will surely lose some data and lose the folder structure (there's thousands pics divided by year)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover lost partitions.

Comment: but my partition shouldnt be lost... its just corrupted

Comment: Try it - what have you got to lose?

Comment: fixed using AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard. Just had to run it, took a while but then it fixed my drive. I could access and save all my files!!!! saved 1tb of pics